# Jenkins Poll scm for specific branch with regex

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I have two Jenkins pipeline jobs:-

1. Main   - Should trigger when there are code changes on `main` branch
2. Branch - Should trigger when there are code changes on any branch other than the `main` branch

I have enabled the `Poll SCM` option for both the jobs that polls for changes every minute on the GitHub repo. Please note that polling is the only feasible option that can be used in my case.

**Branch job config**

[image]

As seen in the configuration of the Branch job it is looking for any branch using `*/*` instead it should be looking for any branch except `main` branch. If I try to add any regex there like `(?!.*main).*$` then Jenkins gives an error as it can't parse the regex.
Would really appreciate if someone can point out a way of making this work.

**FYI:** The `Jenkinsfile` has the pipeline stages - build, test and publish as checkout is handled from the pipeline config itself.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Additional Behaviours*  section there is an option called **Strategy for choosing what to build**.
When you add it you will have several options for the *Choosing strategy*, one of them is **Inverse**:

> Build all branches except for those which match the branch specifiers configure above. This is useful, for example, when you have jobs building your master and various release branches and you want a second job which builds all new feature branches — i.e. branches which do not match these patterns — without redundantly building master and the release branches again each time they change.

So just add the option, set it to **Inverse** and set your *Branch Specifier* to `*/main` - this will cause the job to run for any branch that is not the main branch (or any other branch specified in the pattern).

[image]

Another approach you can take is creating a single job for all branches, and then separate the different stages logic using the built-in [branch](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) condition for the `when` directive:

```groovy
stage('Tests'){
   when { 
       branch 'master'
    }
    steps {
       ...
    }
}
stage('Upload'){
   when { 
       branch pattern: "release-\\d+", comparator: "REGEXP"
    }
    steps {
       ...
    }
}
```

This is very useful when most of the code is the same for all branches, but you have some additional stages for specific branches.

Comment: Now what's happening is the job is running for all the past commits as well, I want to build only the latest changes which comes after configuring the job, any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: @ParagKadam this is how the scm pull works for Git, it tries to catch up all needed branches, but this is done a single time, you can let it run once and from there on it will be synchronized. If it really bothers you you can add another *Strategy for choosing what to build* but this time choose the **Ancestry** option and set a Maximum Age of Commit to the last day or something - which will cause the build to skip all old branches (commits) from the history.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it is still building the `main` branch after doing the config you suggested. I checked-in code in branch named `pipeline` still the `main` branch got triggered. It could be possible that it is building some old commit from `main` but I suggest that shouldn't happen as I have ancestory 1. And the last commit on `main` is older than a week atleast.